# Convert Wolfram code into C language

Tags: conversion

**Here is my *Mathematica* code**:

```
f[x_] := x^2 + 4 x + 4; Solve[f[x] == 9, x]
```

I tried to convert it to *C* but failed.

*Here is the code for conversion*:

```
CForm[f[x_] := x^2 + 4 x + 4]
```

and this

```
CForm[f[x_] := x^2 + 4 x + 4; Solve[f[x] == 9, x]]
```

The former one just outputs `Null`, the latter one just converts the final result in the below

```
List(List(Rule(x,-5)),
   List(Rule(x,1)))
```

Comment: From help it says `Standard arithmetic functions and certain control structures are translated. ` and `No declarations are generated.`. So `CForm` is limited to basic expressions that have direct C mapping. Also, What would CForm translate `Solve` command to in C?  Since C do not have build in Solve command.  If you do `CForm[x^2 + 4 x + 4]` then it translate it.

Comment: I can't understand why you want to do what you asking for. What would you expect the C code to look like? How would use translation in C program if you had it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mathematica does not currently have any facilities to expose complex symbolic functionality, such as `Solve`, to C. To be precise, this is not possible without having access to a full Mathematica installation and explicitly calling it e.g. through [MathLink (see chapter 2)](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf).

As for [`CForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CForm.html), its purpose is to convert simple arithmetic expressions to C syntax, not to convert full programs.